# Run CheckDisk with RedirectStandardOutput

Tags: c#, wpf, process

Running `ChkDsk` without redirecting `StandardOutput` works without an error like this:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"chkdsk.exe", "D:");
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
if (process.ExitCode != 0)
    throw new Exception("did not work");
```

When redirecting StandardOutput, the process ends with `ExitCode 3`.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"chkdsk.exe", "D:");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
if (process.ExitCode != 0)
    throw new Exception("did not work");
```

Doing the same thing with e.g. net use and redirected StandardOutput works without an error

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"net ", "use");
```

Why? How can `chkdsk` be executed and `StandardOutput` be redirected?

Environment: Win 7 Pro x64, UAC disabled, Logged on as Administrator, Dot Net 4.0, VS 2012, WPF Application

Comment: Is this similar? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f9dd591d-d676-40a3-a48c-7987ed8e2ee9/execute-chkdsk-and-display-its-output-in-c

Comment: A couple of side notes: 1) If reading the output as gunr2171 suggests in his link, you must make your call to read before your call to WaitForExit(); 2) You can only synchronously read EITHER StandardOutput OR StandardError. To read both, you must either use a combination of synchronous/asynchronous approaches, or read both asynchronously. That is noted here, by MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, please note that Chkdsk can exit with a code > 0 and still have been successful. See the section on exit codes at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714.aspx

Comment: Checkdisk normaly takes several seconds to be executed. Exiting with code 3 happens without a delay. This means that I'm sure it exits unsuccessfully. Meanwhile I've tried to asyc read StandardOutput and ErrorOutput via OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived events. This did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this code with no problem and with an exit code of `0`.

```
var cd = RunProcessDirect("chkdsk.exe", "c:", false);

protected ConsoleData RunProcessDirect(string processPath, string args, 
    bool isHidden)
{
    Process process = SetupProcess(processPath, args, isHidden);
    process.Start();

    ConsoleData data = new ConsoleData();
    data.StandardOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    data.StandardError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    data.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;

    return data;
}

private Process SetupProcess(string processPath, string args, 
    bool isHidden)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = isHidden 
        ? ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden 
        : ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = isHidden;
    startInfo.FileName = processPath;
    startInfo.Arguments = args;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    return process;
}

public class ConsoleData
{
    public string StandardOutput { get; set; }
    public string StandardError { get; set; }
    public int ExitCode { get; set; }
}
```

`cd.StandardOutput` contained all the text output from the program, `cd.StandardError` was empty, and `cd.ExitCode` is `0`.

Don't worry about the `IsHidden` stuff, that is just extra flair on my method that I didn't feel like taking off.

Comment: Your code works in a ConsoleApplication. As soon as I try to include it in a WPF application, it also exits with ExitCode 3. I'm wondering what is the difference?

Comment: @sam, it might be (and I'm totally guessing here) that in a console app it will launch a process with a higher permission set than WPF. If that is the case, see terry's answer. What was the values in `cd` from the WPF version?

Comment: taking a working console application with your posted code, changing projectfile content from <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> to <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType> results in cd.ErrorCode 3 and  cd.StandardOutput and cd.StandardError are both string.Empty. VS2012 runs in both cases as Administrator.

Comment: just saw the comments,i run it in a wpf app WITH visual studio as administrator and voilÀ it worked,placed as a test textbox and redirected output to there and all info was shown.

Answer (score 1):

You must be running Visual Studio as Administrator and it will execute or you can add a application manifest file(add->new item->general->application manifest file) and changing this line `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` to this `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` which will just promp you to restart visual studio as administrator.

Comment: sorry, this did not help

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, start a console process on non console application; if you would like to redirect standard output, please do a redirect standard input as well (even you are not using it).

So, just add below two lines in your code, it will work.

```
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works, runs chkdsk via cmd, and writes into log whole chkdsk output.

```
public int StartCheckDisc()
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "/C chkdsk C:",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            }
        };

        process.Start();

        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        var errorCode = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        Log.Instance.Info(output);
        Log.Instance.Info(exitCode);
        Log.Instance.Info(errorCode);

        process.WaitForExit();

        return exitCode;
    }
```