# Stuck while trying to run "cmd.exe /c SYSTEMINFO" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process, cmd

I'm trying to run the following code in my C# WPF application. Whenever I use something like dir (I should probably mention the output is the directory of my working folder in Visual Studio, not System32), it allows it. However, if I use systeminfo or set the working directory to C:\Windows\System32, it hangs...

```
        MessageBox.Show("STARTED");

        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c systeminfo") {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            //WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\"
        };

        // *** Redirect the output ***
        Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);

        if (process == null) return false;
        process.WaitForExit();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToLower();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        MessageBox.Show(output);
        MessageBox.Show(error);
        MessageBox.Show(exitCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c \"systeminfo\"")`

Comment: What happens if you set `CreateNoWindow` to false (so it shows the command prompt window) and run it? Does it show any messages?

Comment: @dr_andonuts Didn't work. :(

Comment: @gunr2171, no. It just shows the cursor.

Comment: You realize that if you redirect the output, you have to read the output, right? If you don't, it will fill the pipe's buffer and suspend the thread trying to print something out.

Comment: Perhaps `systeminfo` is hanging.  Have you tried this in another terminal?

Comment: Take a look at [this possibly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20076929).

Comment: @gunr2171 But actually, if I terminate the batch (^C), it will output what I want.

Comment: You could, rather then redirecting to a C pipe, add `> filename` to the end of the argument list.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I edited the question to show the rest of it. (Sorry, I thought I included that part too)

Comment: @Amorphous: No, not like your updated code. You have to read it BEFORE waiting for the process to exit. If you wait for the process to exit and it prints too much, it will hang and never exit, and you still won't have read the output to unhang it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried this and works as expected.
Of course you need to read the redirected output before the process closes.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c systeminfo") 
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\"
};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Process p = Process.Start(processInfo);
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Why are you starting p twice?